# How do I automatically insert a partial filename in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I'd like to get InDesign to insert the first few digits of a filename automatically in a document created from a template.

Our filenames are in this format:

XXXXX_Name1_Name2_Name3.indd

The Xs before the underscore represent the job number.  It can be wither 4 or 5 digits. I know InDesign can automatically place the entire filename. I'd just like it to insert the job number portion.Is there a way to do this either with GREP styles or (preferably) some sort of scripting? Ideally, it would require little to no input from the user.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have one filename to be inserted for one new document or do you need to insert more than one filenames to one (new) document?  I guess that this question should be on a side with scripting expertise ...  Nevertheless, Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Thanks, Kurt - It's just one filename. It's a template, so it will open as 'Untitled-1.' Then it will be saved into the format I listed above. Does that help? (And do you know of any scripting resources where I could find someone to create this script?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Text Variables, you cannot get the built-in type "File Name" to show only part of the actual file name; it's all or nothing. You *can* create a "Custom Text" variable and assign it anything you want, but you have to remember to update it with the job number part of the filename. <s>Only the latter can be automated with a Javascript, and so you still need to **run** the script every time you save the document under a new name.</s> InDesign keeps on surprising me, it wasn't half as hard as I initially believed...

Save the below script as `UpdateJobNumber.jsx` in the **Startup Scripts** folder in your Scripts Panel folder; you will need to restart InDesign for it to take effect. In your template, create a new variable called `JobNumber` and place it anywhere you like. Henceforth, after saving a document under a new name that starts with one or more digits, the text variable `JobNumber` will automagically be updated!

...GREP styles have absolutely nothing to do with this. I know: GREP may seem to be able to do magic, at times. But it cannot do *anything*. This, for example, is way, way out of its scope.

```
//DESCRIPTION:Update Job Number Variable
// Another Jongware Script 18-Nov-2014
#targetengine "updateJobNumber"

app.addEventListener("afterSaveAs", updateJobNumber, false); 

function updateJobNumber ()
{
    if (app.activeDocument.saved)
    {
        varRef = app.activeDocument.textVariables.item("JobNumber");
        if (varRef.isValid)
        {
            fileId = app.activeDocument.fullName.name.match(/^\d+/);
            if (fileId)
            {
                if (varRef.variableOptions.contents != fileId[0])
                {
                    varRef.variableOptions.contents = fileId[0];
                    app.activeDocument.save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Here is my older script, which could still be useful to update manually. Ordinarily you would not need it.)

```
//DESCRIPTION:Fill in Job Number Variable
// A Jongware Script 18-Nov-2014
if (app.activeDocument.saved)
{
    varRef = app.activeDocument.textVariables.item("JobNumber");
    if (!varRef.isValid)
            varRef = app.activeDocument.textVariables.add({name:"JobNumber"});
    fileId = app.activeDocument.fullName.name.match(/^\d+/);
    if (fileId)
        varRef.variableOptions.contents = fileId[0];
    else
        varRef.variableOptions.contents = "<INVALID>";
}
```

---

(After writing the above) I just thought of a nice alternative trick using the native "File Name" Text Variable. But it will only work (nicely) if (1) the job number always appears at the same place, (2) in a font where digits are all the same width, and (3) you always would have the same number of digits (which you don't, as I understand it).

Insert a File Name text variable in a text frame large enough to contain the *entire* name. Draw a rectangle on top of the part you want to see--the digits. Cut the text frame and Paste Into the rectangle.

The advantage is this will automagically get updated by InDesign itself after each save. A major disadvantage, however, is that it's unaware of the number of digits in the file name; so if these happen to be more than you expected, the last ones will be lost, and if less, you will see a part of the rest of the file name.